# What are the common chords formed?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, circles

[image]

The common chords that I found here were this . (According to me )

C1-C1’ and C1 with C1’-C4’. That equals 4.Then , C2 with C1’-C4’. That equals total of 8.

Then C1 with C1 and similarly til C3 equals 3.

Then , C1’ with C1’ and till C4’.4

Now , my answer is 15 but in book it is 12.

Please tell me where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Circle $C_1$ has one chord in common with each of the $4$ primed circles.

Same for $C_2$ and $C_3$.

That makes $12$ common chords.

Another way to look at it is to take away all but one circle in each of $G_1$ and $G_2$. In this case it's clear that there's only one common chord. There are $3\times 4$ such pairs of circles.